# Name that airport!

Tags: visual

What is the name of the airport?

When (to within 5 years) was the photo taken?

What else can you say about it?

[image]

Comment: Reverse google search: http://www.northantstelegraph.co.uk/news/shoreham-airport-stands-in-for-nazi-vienna-in-helen-mirren-film-woman-in-gold-1-6682100

Comment: 5 minutes 8 seconds - howzat!

Comment: Grr - I'll make the next picture one more difficult.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is more of a trivia/google search question than a puzzle.

Comment: It's a puzzle in the sense that Nazi flags are flying in front of a British airport in 2015.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK 2014, actually! </pedant>

Comment: @Len has a point. If you take the above image and drag it onto the search bar for https://images.google.com, you get the accepted answer as a top result. See http://bit.ly/1PvMEnD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The airport is

> Shoreham Airport, West Sussex.

The date is

> 5 June 2014.

The reason is

> the airport was being used as a film set for the shooting of the film *Woman in Gold* set during World War 2.

If you want proof, you can find a newspaper article featuring the picture [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2649923/Outrage-actors-dressed-Nazis-takeover-Kent-airport-24-hours-70th-anniversary-D-day-film-scenes-Ryan-Reynolds-film.html).